# sed replace new line character inside each line

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sed, command-line

I have a huge csv file from an export delimited by pipe

```
8CDAC2EF-9261-4B9F-9D41-87B460C467B0|SAMPLE1|SAMPLE 2|SAMPLE 3|2020-08-03 00:00:00
8CDAC2EF-9261-4B9F-9D41-87B460C467B0|SAMPLE1|SAMPLE 

2|SAMPLE 3|2020-08-03 00:00:00
8CDAC2EF-9261-4B9F-9D41-87B460C467B0|SAMPLE1|SAMPLE 2|

|2020-08-03 00:00:00
8CDAC2EF-9261-4B9F-9D41-87B460C467B0|SAMPLE1|SAMPLE 2||2020-08-03 00:00:00
8CDAC2EF-9261-4B9F-9D41-87B460C467B0|SAMPLE1||SAMPLE 3|2020-08-03 00:00:00
```

Ideally, the first line is the expected format, however, since its raw data, there seems some new line character in the fields `SAMPLE 2`, `SAMPLE 3`. I would like to replace the new line or breaking characters in these fields with empty character so it becomes the format of the first line.

PS: The `SAMPLE 2` and `SAMPLE 3` could be null as well.

I wanted to make this to the below format, ie, double quote enclosed as below.

```
"8CDAC2EF-9261-4B9F-9D41-87B460C467B0"|"SAMPLE1"|"SAMPLE 2"|"SAMPLE 3"|"2020-08-03 00:00:00"
```

I tried the below code, it works fine, but breaks if there are any new line characters each line.

```
sed  -e 's/^\|$/"/g' -e 's/|/"|"/g'  input.csv
```

Edit: The accepted solution works fine, but since I have some kind of raw data, I had do follow some additional steps since some of the values contain `|` and other special strings which shouldn't be there.

What I did was following.

1. I was able to control the delimiter from the export, I used `€` since we find that it's not used in the data in any of our samples.
2. Then I replaced `"`, `'`, `|`, with a space character. finally, the delimiter of `€` was replaced with `|`.
3. Then used the accepted answer to filter out line breaks
4. Finally piped them to make those are enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe '$c += tr/|//; if ($c == 4) { $c = 0 } else { chomp }' -- file.csv
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, prints each line after running the code
- `tr///` is normally used for transliteration, but here, it's just the fast method to count how many vertical bars are there on the current line. We add the count to the variable `$c`.
- If `$c` is four, the line is complete, so we clear the variable.
- if `$c` isn't four, the line is not yet complete (it can also be too long if the data are wrong, but let's ignore this now). So, we run [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) to remove the newline.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed '
    :a
    /\([^|]*|\)\{4\}/!{
      N
      s/\n//
      ba
   }' input.csv
```